# Order of redirecting stderr and stdout to the same file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line-interface

When redirecting both stderr and stdout to same file, why is it necessary to redirect stderr to stdout after we redirect the stdout to file?
How does it work and why is the reverse way not allowed?

Answer (score 2):

With `yourcmd > file 2>&1`, the standard output is sent to `file` then `stderr` is redirected to what the standard output goes, that is `file`.

With `yourcmd 2>&1 > file`, the `stderr` is sent to where current `stdout` goes (most likely your terminal) and then current `stdout` is redirected to `file`.

Answer (score 2):

The `2>&1` works like this:

```
1 --->  output               1 --------> output
                   =====>          /
2 --->  error                2 ---/
```

not this:

```
1 --->  output                      -->  1 ----> output
                   =====>          /
2 --->  error                2 ---/
```

so that standard error will be whatever standard output is *then*, not what it *will be*.

For more information and cool ASCII art, visit the [Illustrated redirection tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) recommended by [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to *redirect stderr to stdout after we redirect the stdout to file*, you could use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout. Or `1>&2` to redirect stdout to stder. You can also redirect `1>` and `2>` separately (if you choose). As an example,

```
echo a 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

will output nothing on the terminal (but you get `a` if you use `echo a 2>/dev/null`; because it redirects stderr to `/dev/null`).

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question I'll quote the Redirection wiki from [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) by [Greycat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat) and [Lhunath](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Lhunath).

I suggest you to visit [Bash FAQ 55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) before other links in this post, as it will answer your question faster, while other links will help you in capturing a more global understanding of Redirections.

> ### Redirection
>
> Redirection is the shell's mechanism for opening, closing, duplicating, and performing other manipulations on [file descriptors](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor). Redirection is either the last or second-to-last (depending on the shell and command) step of simple-command evaluation prior to running the command itself.
>
> ## Links
>
> - [Illustrated redirection tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) (**recommended**), [redirection reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection), and [understanding the copy descriptor](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/copydescriptor) on the bash-hackers wiki.
> - The [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) includes complete documentation. A quick reference is available on the [BashSheet](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Redirection).
> - [FAQ 55](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) provides a basic introduction, and the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection) has a very short non-technical introduction.
> - The portable types of redirects are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)